# Jqgrid cannot add or edit data

Tags: javascript, php, jqgrid

I am using the jqgrid from Trirand.com and I'm unable to add or edit by data through the built in form dialogs. When I edit and or add data and hit submit the data refreshes but nothing changes. I've checked PHPmyadmin and no data has been changed or added to the database.

Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT**

HTML/Jquery code

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function(){ 
          jQuery("#grid").jqGrid("initFontAwesome").jqGrid({
              pager:'#pager',
              url:'getunits.php',
              datatype: "json",
              mtype: 'GET',
              height: 300,
              width: 1000,
              colNames:['Unit Id', 'Div Id', 'Title Org', 'Short Desc', 'Long Desc', 'Comments', 'Enabled'],
              colModel:[
                        {name:'unit_id',
                            index:'unit_id', 
                            width:40,
                            editable:true,
                            sortable:false, 
                            resizable:false,
                            align:"center", 
                            editoptions:{size:7,maxlength:6},
                            editrules:{required:true,number:true},
                            formoptions:{elmprefix:"(*)"}
                        },
                        {name:'div_id',
                            index:'div_id', 
                            width:30,
                            editable:true,
                            sortable:false, 
                            resizable:false,
                            align:"center", 
                            editoptions:{size:4,maxlength:4},
                            editrules:{required:true,number:true},
                            formoptions:{elmprefix:"(*)"}
                        },
                        {name:'title_org',
                            index:'title_org', 
                            width:60,
                            editable:true,
                            sortable:false, 
                            resizable:false,
                            editoptions:{size:11,maxlength:11},
                            editrules:{required:true,number:true},
                            formoptions:{elmprefix:"(*)"}
                        },
                        {name:'short_desc',
                            index:'short_desc', 
                            width:50,
                            editable:true,
                            resizable:false,
                            sortable:false,
                            editoptions:{size:7,maxlength:10},
                            editrules:{required:true},
                            formoptions:{elmprefix:"(*)"}
                        },
                        {name:'long_desc',
                            index:'long_desc', 
                            width:230,
                            editable:true,
                            resizable:false,
                            sortable:false,
                            edittype:"textarea",
                            editoptions:{rows:"2",cols:"30",maxlength:60},
                            editrules:{required:true},
                            formoptions:{elmprefix:"(*)"}
                        },
                        {name:'unit_desc',
                            index:'unit_desc', 
                            width:230,
                            editable:true,
                            resizable:false,
                            sortable:false,
                            edittype:"textarea",
                            editoptions:{rows:"2",cols:"30",maxlength:60}
                        },
                        {name:'avail_ind',
                            index:'avail_ind',
                            width:40,
                            editable:true,
                            resizable:false,
                            sortable:false,
                            align:"center",
                            edittype:"select",
                            editoptions:{value:"Y:Y;N:N"}
                        }
                   ],

              pager: jQuery('#gridpager'),
              viewrecords: true,
              sortorder: "asc",
              sortname: "div_id",
              caption:"Unit Codes",
              editurl:'getunits.php',
              toppager:true, 
              recordtext:'', 
              hidegrid:false, 
              scroll:true,
              rowNum:"10000"

         }); 

         jQuery("#grid").jqGrid('navGrid','#grid_toppager', 
        {

            add:true,
            edit:true,
            view:true, 
            search:false, 
            del:false, 
            refresh:false
        },

        { // Edit form
            width:"auto",
            height:"auto",
            top:220,
            left:500,
            viewPagerButtons:false, 
            topinfo:"Fields marked with (*) are required",
            resize:false
        },

        { // Add form
            width:"auto",
            height:"auto",
            top:220,
            left:500,
            topinfo:"Fields marked with (*) are required",
            resize:false,
            reloadAfterSubmit:true,
            closeAfterAdd: true   
        },

        { // prmDel 

       },

       { //prmSearch

       },

       { //prmView
            top:220,
            left:460
       }


       );   


        }); // jQuery("#grid").jqGrid 
</script>
```

PHP Code

```
<?php 

$dbhost = "localhost"; 
$dbuser = "root"; 
$dbpass = "*******"; 
$dbname = "fdmamaint"; 


$page = $_GET['page']; // get the requested page
$limit = $_GET['rows']; // get how many rows we want to have into the grid
$sidx = $_GET['sidx']; // get index row - i.e. user click to sort
$sord = $_GET['sord']; // get the direction

if(!$sidx) $sidx =1;

// connect to the database
$db = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die("Connection Error: " . mysql_error());

mysql_select_db($dbname) or die("Error conecting to db.");
$result = mysql_query('SELECT unit_id, div_id, title_org, short_desc, long_desc, unit_desc, avail_ind FROM depunits where avail_ind="Y" and active_ind="Y"');
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC);
$count = $row['count'];

if( $count >0 ) 
{
    $total_pages = cell($count/$limit);
} 
else 
{
        $total_pages = 0;
}

if ($page > $total_pages) $page=$total_pages;
$start = $limit*$page - $limit; // do not put $limit*($page - 1)
$SQL = 'SELECT unit_id, div_id, title_org, short_desc, long_desc, unit_desc, avail_ind FROM depunits where avail_ind="Y" and active_ind="Y"';
$result = mysql_query( $SQL ) or die("Couldn t execute query.".mysql_error());

$response->page = $page;
$response->total = $total_pages;
$response->records = $count;

$i=0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $response->rows[$i]['id']=$row[unit_id];
    $response->rows[$i]['cell']=array($row[unit_id],$row[div_id],$row[title_org],$row[short_desc],$row[long_desc],$row[unit_desc],$row[avail_ind]);
    $i++;
}        
echo json_encode($response);

?>
```

**UPDATED**

EditDivisions.php

```
<?php

$dbhost = "localhost"; 
$dbuser = "root"; 
$dbpass = "*****"; 
$dbname = "fdmamaint"; 

// connect to the database
$mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die("Connection Error: " . mysql_error());

mysql_select_db($dbname) or die("Error conecting to db.");

$div = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['div_id']);
$l2 = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['l2_id']);
$l1l2 = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['l1l2_id']);
$l1l3 = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['l1l3_id']);
$l2l3 = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['l2l3_id']);
$beg = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['exec_beg']);
$end = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['exec_end']);
$csa = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['csa_id']);
$area = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['area_id']);
$areadesc = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['area_desc']);
$shortdesc = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['short_desc']);
$longdesc = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['long_desc']);
$enabled = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['avail_ind']);

if($_GET['oper']=='add'){

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO depdivisions (div_id, l1l2_id, l2_id, l1l3_id, l2l3_id, exec_beg, exec_end, csa_id, area_id, area_desc, short_desc, long_desc, avail_ind) values ($div,$l1l2,$l2,$l1l3,$l2l3,$beg,$end,$csa,$area,$areadesc,$shortdesc,$longdesc,$enabled");

}else if($_GET['oper']=='edit'){

}else if($_GET['oper']=='del'){

}

?>
```

Comment: can you please add your code with post

Comment: You just select in your add/edit php code ? Where are your insert and update code ??

Comment: @kmas I was under the impression that there are built in functions inside the grid base code that handles them. Wouldn't it be inside the jquery.jqGrid.src.js?

Answer (score 0):

To answer the JCooper comment (  `I was under the impression that there are built in functions inside the grid base code that handles them. Wouldn't it be inside the jquery.jqGrid.src.js?` ).

How it works :

In your edit php page/file (`getunits.php`, not sure it is a good choice because it is the same URL as your "load_data" URL), you have to check if the user adds, edits or deletes :

```
// Here, we use $_GET, because you ask for it in configuration.
$unit_id = $_GET['unit_id']; // And so on for the other form values

if($_GET['oper']=='add'){
   // mysql insert
}else if($_GET['oper']=='edit'){
   // mysql update
}else if($_GET['oper']=='del'){
   // mysql delete
}
```

When the operation is done, the grid is load again with the "load_data" URL.

Comment: How do I reference the user data to pass into the insert statement values?

Comment: In the colModel array, you use `name:'unit_id'` ==> you get this value with `$_GET['unid_id']`.

Comment: I have updated my original post to include my edit file. I am now getting a "Internal Server Error 500" when I try to add rows.

Comment: Your insert is bad, the quotes are missing around your "string" column. Error 500 can be so many things. Add error log (apache).

Comment: I tried added quotes around my string column and got the same error. I was unable to find an error log or how to create one. I am using IIS7 instead of apache.

Comment: Ask another question (create a new topic) because now you've got a SQL error. IIS7 can log the error, but I don't know IIS7.